# blocking IO method throw NoSuchException in while loop - Java

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am new to socket programming and not very familiar with I/O class.

In the following codes, I am making a simple socket program and use while loop to make it able to accept clientSocket for more than one time. The codes were executed well in the first iteration while throws NoSuchElementException when it reaches header = in.nextLine() (in the run method of the thread). I thought the method is blocking and should wait for the input? Similar things happen when I call next().

Can anyone help me understand this? I will greatly appreciate it!

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
    int num = 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
            new ClientSocket(clientSocket, num++).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listenSocket.close();
    }
}

private static class ClientSocket extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private int numOfSocket;

    public ClientSocket(Socket s, int num) {
        socket = s;
        numOfSocket = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        //get file location
        String header;
        String fileLocation = null;
        Scanner in = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            // Get header && extract file location
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));

            header = in.nextLine();

            System.out.println(header);
            String[] headerArr = header.split(" ");
            String url = headerArr[1];
            fileLocation = url.substring(1);
            System.out.println(fileLocation);

            // Try to get the file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
            System.out.println("file found");
            out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            out.flush();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("file not found");
            out.println("HTTP/1.1 404 File not found\n");
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("fileNotFound.html"));
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                out.flush();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException a) {
                System.out.println(a.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

More Clarifications:
So I ran it in Netbeans IDE and used a Chrome browser as a client to test it. It worked well in the first few attempts and then started to throw exceptions. The client is not affected and can still get the correct response. Just the server side is affected. Here is the message from the console.

> Blockquote

```
GET /hah HTTP/1.1
hah
file not foundGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
favicon.ico
file not foundGET /test.html HTTP/1.1
test.html
file found
Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception 
in thread "Thread-4" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

> Blockquote

Comment: When I try to execute your code, i do not get such exception. What I did: copied your code into class, run, telnet to localhost on port 8888 and write string `<some text><space><some text>`. As soon as I do not have any files your code looks for, I got exception, but correct `FileNotFoundException`. So could you please add some info on how you run this/test this?

Comment: The line terminator in HTML is `\r\n`, not `\n`. You don't need an entire `Scanner` just to copy a file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

@Evgeny I have posted my console logs. Can you see if you have the same issue?

Comment: @EJP Can you explain a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: I can reproduce such exception in case when I frequently push reload in Chrome. So, suppose, problem is that chrome closes connection before sending end of line, and as result scanner throws an exception as soon as no more lines available in stream (because it is closed).

Comment: @Evgeny seems I have found the cause. I used Chrome and Chrome will send two requests at the same time. This leads to a thread reading nothing and then throw exception. I will find a time to post more detailed answers from someone else's post. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I figured out. It was the problem of the client(which was the Chrome browser)

When Chrome was visiting my server, it was actually sending 2 request. With one of my original request and the other is generated automatically to fetch meta data. Since my server is a simple and for educational purpose, it was not designed to handle errors not expected.

So the conclusion is that the codes works fine for its original purpose, but needs to be more robust in practical situations.